# Xcode 4 Can't Create Subversion Repository

Tags: xcode, svn

We've got 4 developers using Xcode and working from a Subversion repository located on a remote server.  A new developer is using Xcode 4.6 but cannot create a repository entry.

On the 'Add a repository' window where you give it a name, enter a url and select a type - the only type available on his machine is 'git'.  Subversion isn't an option.

Subversion is installed on his machine - 1.6.18 (same as the rest of us have) and he can use it from the command line.

Any ideas why Xcode isn't allowing it as an option?

Comment: Since I wouldn't notice if it was gone, I had to go check and I can only confirm Subversion is still there in Xcode 4.6

Comment: I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and svn 1.7.1. I got this problem today. As exactly @FilipRadelic said, there was no option "Subversion", the only type was Git. Any one can help?